# Turn on Auto Close Tags for HTML in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I recently started a new project in PHPStorm, but noticed that none of my HTML elements are being auto closed like in my other projects.

If I type

```
<div>
```

the editor autoloads the

```
</div>
```

How do I turn this feature back on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can do this by setting your PHPstorm

Go to PHP Storm -> File -> Setting -> Editor -> Smart Keys -> XML/HTML

Check all or what you want, then Press Ok.It is done.

Reference : http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/editor-smart-keys.html

Comment: Setting doesn't exist, URL is dead. Top Google result.

Answer (score 14):

**File > Settings > Editor > Emmet > HTML**

Under **Filters Enabled By Default** tick **Comment Tags**.

You'll then find if you use Emmet's syntax, for example:

`.test#test` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

**It'll output:**

```
<div class="test" id="test"></div>
<!-- /#test.test -->
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful!

Answer (score 8):

If you type `div` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then it will auto-complete for you. PHPStorm has emmet built in in verisons 6 and 7 as far as I know.

Comment: This doesn't work either; tapping Tab just indents after the </

Answer (score 0):

In PHPStorm Version 2017.3 you can change this setting at:

**File > Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys > XML/HTML > Insert closing tag on tag completion**